# Cannot see Model hyperparameters in Model Versions tab

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-automl

I've trained a classifier model based on a tabular data via AutoML and wants to check the model hyperparameters and configurations.

Per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tabular-data/classification-regression/logging), I should be able to check it from the training logs accessible from the model version tab but it doesn't show up. Looking from the Cloud Logging directly I couldn't find any logs associated with TablesModelStructure.

[image]